# ListView: adding a item and then with back button go back to refreshed list

Tags: android

I have a problem with my android app.

I have a `ListView` and this `ListView` get the data from a Database and I bind it via a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Now I have a button to add a new entry to the database, then a new intent is started and I create a new item and add it to the database. After adding it, I go to a new page.

Now I want to have the following:

When I get to the new page, and I press the back button, I don't want to be forwarded to the create new item page, I want to skip it and go directly back to the `ListView`.
The other problem, is that the `ListView` should then display the new entry. It should refresh in some way.

How to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you create your new Intent to add the item to the database, make sure you set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` so that the new Intent is not kept in the history stack
   eg: `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)`
2. When an adapters underlying data is changed and you want the change to reflect in your ListView, call the adapters `notifyDataSetChanged()` method (in your case, on clicking the back button)
   eg: `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

First, start your activity (that adds new elements to the database) with `startActivityForResult()`, so when that activity is finished (for example by pressing the back button) the `onActivityResult()` callback will be called on the calling activity (the one with the list). In this method, run the query again that fills the list, create a new `SimpleCursorAdapter` with the resulting cursor, and give it to the list via `setAdapter()`.